# How to load RubyMotion table view cell data from file

Tags: rubymotion, rubymotion-promotion

I'm getting started with RubyMotion and ProMotion. I'm building a table view and I would like to move the data out into an external file to make it easier to manage. Here's what I have so far:

```
class MasterScreen < PM::TableScreen
  title 'States'

  def table_data
    [{
      title: "Northwest States",
      cells: [
        { title: "Oregon", action: :view_details, arguments: { state: @oregon }},
        { title: "Washington", action: :view_details, arguments: { state: @washington }}
      ]
    }]
  end

  def view_details
    open DetailScreen.new(nav_bar: true)
  end
end
```

I'd like to move the names of the states (basically the cell titles) into something like a YAML or JSON file that I can load and iterate over. How can I achieve something like this?

---

**Update:** I managed to figure out how to load text from a file.

First I added `bubble-wrap` to my `Gemfile` and ran `bundle install`. BubbleWrap provides the helper method `App.resources_path`.

In `my_app/resources/states.txt` I have a list of states, separated by new lines:

```
Oregon
Washington
Foobar
```

In my Table View Controller, I read the file and split the file into an array of lines.

```
class MasterScreen < PM::TableScreen
  title 'States'

  def on_load
    data = File.read("#{App.resources_path}/states.txt")
    @states = data.lines
  end

  def table_data
    [{
      title: "Northwest States",
      cells: @states.map do |state|
        {
          title: state,
          action: :view_details,
          arguments: { state: state }
        }
      end
    }]
  end

  def view_details(arguments)
    open DetailScreen.new(nav_bar: true, title: arguments[:state])
  end
end
```

This works, but it's only part of what I was trying to do. I would still like to use a structure like YAML to represent titles and subtitles. What would be the RubyMotion way to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it. I came across a RubyMotion gem called [`motion-yaml`](https://github.com/HipByte/motion-yaml). Simply add it to your Gemfile, add your YAML file to your `resources` directory, and use it like you would YAML in Ruby.

```
data = YAML.load(File.read("#{App.resources_path}/my_yaml_file.yml"))
```

Note: You will need to add `bubble-wrap` to your Gemfile in order to have the `App.resources_path`. I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do it without bubble-wrap.

Comment: Just look at the implementation provided by BubbleWrap `def resources_path; NSBundle.mainBundle.resourcePath; end` it's not giving much apart from a nicer name